# freeradius 3.0.20 Unknown or invalid value "System" for attribute Auth-Type

Tags: redhat, radius

The radius service can't startup and show following error message:

Wed Aug 16 11:55:56 2023 : Error: /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[215]: Parse error (check) for entry raeho: Unknown or invalid value "System" for attribute Auth-Type
Wed Aug 16 11:55:56 2023 : Error: Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
Wed Aug 16 11:55:56 2023 : Error: /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"

And the /etc/raddb/users file as below:

```
raeho           Huntgroup-Name == "ciscoas9r", Auth-Type = System
                Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
                Cisco-AVPair = "shell:priv-lvl=15",
                Reply-Message = "Hello ciscoas9r, %{User-Name}",
                Fall-Through = Yes
```

The OS version is Redhat Enterprise Linux 8.8 and freeradius-3.0.20-14